# Use <ul> as ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to integrate a web application developed by third party with my website.

It displays a list of course categories and course list. Developer doesn't give me access to application. I was asked to display the categories as image block and courses as numbered list.

I have checked the list using firebug. I found the `id` and `class` and it’s in `<ul>` unordered list.

I used the following for categories:

```css
ul#category-list li:nth-child(1){
  background-image: url("images/adm1.jpg");
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
}
ul#category-list li:nth-child(2){
  background-image: url("images/adm2.jpg");
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
}
ul#category-list li:nth-child(3){
  background-image: url("images/adm2.jpg");
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
}
ul#category-list li:nth-child(4){
  background-image: url("images/adm1.jpg");
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

for courses. It’s in `<ul>`; there is no way to change to `<ol>` (this will solve the issue). Is there any way I can achieve this using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set the `list-style-type` as `decimal` for the `ul` and it would automatically work like a `ol`.

By *display as ordered list*, I assume you meant the numbers should be 1, 2, 3. If you want it to be i, ii, iii then use the value as `lower-roman` instead of `decimal` or if as I, II, III then set it as `upper-roman`.

```css
ul#course-list {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
ul#course-list-2 {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
ul#course-list-3 {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<ul id='course-list'>
  <li>Course 1</li>
  <li>Course 2</li>
  <li>Course 3</li>
  <li>Course 4</li>
  <li>Course 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id='course-list-2'>
  <li>Course 1</li>
  <li>Course 2</li>
  <li>Course 3</li>
  <li>Course 4</li>
  <li>Course 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id='course-list-3'>
  <li>Course 1</li>
  <li>Course 2</li>
  <li>Course 3</li>
  <li>Course 4</li>
  <li>Course 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Though the above is a solution, I would still recommend you to speak to the developer and ask them to use the semantically correct tag.